# How can I sign in using a Google account?

Tags: vb.net, webforms

I have a VB.NET web form website that I up until now have been using an SQL server with user data used to let the users login. I now want to use Google sign-in instead. I cannot find any good example that works. Anyone know any good examples?

Comment: Please see [**how to ask**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)... you are not new here and should be aware of how asking a question works.

Comment: One search term that works is "google sign in api".

Comment: You are here from a while, you should know how to ask and what to do. Here some usefull [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) about google sign in api for asp.net